# Defining 'empty' on Heap Typeclass

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to copy the ML code from Purely Functional Data Structures into Haskell.

```
class (Ord a) => Heap a where
    empty :: Heap a
    ...
```

But I get this compile-time error:

```
Prelude> :l Heap.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Heap.hs, interpreted )

Heap.hs:2:18:
    Expected kind ‘*’, but ‘Heap a’ has kind ‘Constraint’
    In the type ‘Heap a’
    In the class declaration for ‘Heap’
```

It seems appropriate to me that `empty` should be a function in the **Heap** type-class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `empty` have the signature `a` instead of `Heap a`?

Comment: **EDIT**: In the book, it says `val empty : Heap`, so I assume that means `empty` should return a `Heap a`...

Comment: but there `Map` is a `data`, not a `class`...

Comment: maybe I shouldn't have a type-class then? Coming from scala/java, perhaps I'm trying to use an `interface` where a `class` (or maybe ADT in Haskell) should be used?

Comment: Haskell's `class` is indeed more some kind of interface. I think you better define a datatype (with `data`) and implement an `empty` function on top of that.

Comment: You can't really translate quite so directly between ML and Haskell. Much of what Okasaki does with ML structures and functors would be done in Haskell with type classes. Note also that ML type and data constructors are lower case, but Haskell ones are upper case.

Comment: If I remember right, one of the appendices of Purely Functional Data Structures has Haskell versions of the code. EDIT: That might only be in hard copies of the book, now that I look again.

Comment: @DavidYoung, it does, but it doesn't implement the algorithms faithfully. Specifically, it's lazier than the ML code, so the worst-case data structures degrade to amortized ones, and he doesn't include the scheduled structures at all. I'm not sure why, but it seems he didn't want to touch Haskell's `seq`.

Answer (score 3):

Type-classes in Haskell are not (that much) related to `class`es in Object-oriented program. To put it simple: a `type-class` groups a set of `data` instances that support a set of functions.

You thus define a class as

```
class Foo a where
    bar :: a -> Bool
    qux :: a
```

That doesn't mean `Foo` is a type, it means that for any datastructure `a`, that is an `instance` of `Foo`, you should implement these methods.

In that sense it's more an **interface**, types itself are instances of a class.

Now you can for instance define a datastructure, for instance a "naive" map approach:

```
data ListMap a b = ListMap [(a,b)]
```

Now that means that every map is stored as a list of `(a,b)` tuples with the `ListMap` "constructor".

You can then for instance define an `empty` method for such listmap:

```
empty :: ListMap a b
empty = ListMap []
```

It thus means that you create a `ListMap` with an empty list.

It can however be useful to construct a `class` in case you are planning to implement multiple datastructures that behave like a map. In that case you can for instance define:

```
class Map a where
    empty :: a
```

Now you can make `ListMap` an instance of `Map` with:

```
instance Map (ListMap a b) where
    empty = ListMap []
```

Later, if you want to define functions that make returns for instance the list of keys, etc. you can define multi-parameter type classes.

Thus to answer your question in short: if you use a class, the `empty` method has the signature `a`, but you should first define a datastructure, a `class` is more what objected oriented programming languages call an "interface".

Comment: Note that if the `empty` method has signature `a`, you'll end up either using MPTC and functional dependencies or (perhaps better) an associated type to actually be able to deal with elements and structures of them. The more usual approach is to use a higher-kinded class, so you have `empty :: map a`

Comment: @dfeuer: well it's only a small introduction that `class`es are not how to define a datastructure. Indeed multiparameter type classes with keytype and value type are better suited for the job.